# WCF + N-tier = why?

Tags: c#, wcf, n-tier-architecture

I'm seen project that use N-tier with WCF. When creating a WCF project in the solution it is often called with the word "service?

The main questions:
Why and what benefit do you have when using WCF in relation to N-tier?

Which situation should be used with WCF and N-tier?

Comment: i think you should clearify how WCF is used...

Comment: I see no architectural difference between a normal web application and a service. The demands on the backend parts are the same, only the frontend changes.

Comment: Isn't this a rather open question that is more suitable on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services have no UI. They expose methods and/or entities (in the case of REST) and return results in data format (typically XML and/or JSON).

WCF is a tool for building services. You cannot build UI's or standalone applications with it, you can only use it to write services that are then consumed by apps/UIs/other services.

There is a difference between layering and tiering, by the way. Tiering generally refers to hardware: a service tier is therefore one or more servers that run one or more services, which connect to other tiers -- business logic running on other servers ("application servers"). Typically you have a UI ("Presentation") layer, calling a service layer (a WCF service), calling a business layer or a domain model, calling a data access layer, calling one or more databases and/or user agents. All this is documented pretty well in Microsoft's own docs, such as the Patterns & Practices Guides: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/bb190351

Answer (score 0):

The situation I find myself in constantly is a thick client connecting to a server in the cloud. We don't want to deploy SQL DBs to all of our clients. We host the DBs and expose access via WCF business data services. The thick clients then connect to the WCF services.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is the well known question of layer vs tier (you can search for SO questions), layer being the logical division tier being the physical. To split a layer into a tier you need a service (and not just a reference to the project assembly). Having a real tier in the middle has a number of benefits
1. You can scale the project by spliting it on separate servers. You can potentially use multiple machines for the client tier.
2. You can have different clients (desktop/web/non-.NET clients) and even use the service as a public API (though that might be risky).
3. You are sure you don't jump over your layers because you have physical separation i.e. it ensures correctness.

That being said I've seen the web service tier approach applied in many project that don't actually need it and most likely will never need it. I believe the introduction of such a layer is often the result of overdesign.

I am also interested in the opinion of more experienced people.